# Does Safari consider subdomains of a 2nd level domain to be 3rd party?

Tags: authentication, cookies, browser, safari, webkit

I'd like to set-up a front-end one one host that authenticates with a back-end on another host. Assuming that the domains are:

- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- api.example.com

Will Safari allow api.example.com to set a cookie in the browser if the request was made while the user was at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no: Safari/WebKit considers sites that share a 2nd-level domain (i.e., `example.com`) to be 1st-party.

We tested this on some sites hosted on our local machines using dummy domains (`www.example.localdev` and `api.example.localdev`) and Safari treated them as 3rd-party. This meant we could not use our client-side site (www) to authenticate a user via our backend (api).

However, upon moving to staging instances on the internet with actual domains (`www.example.com` and `api.example.com`) they were treated as 1st-party and everyone went home happy.

WebKit's [tracking protection](https://webkit.org/tracking-prevention/) describes supporting the subdomain strategy:

> First and third-party. If news.example is shown in the URL bar and it loads a subresource from adtech.example, then news.example is first-party and adtech.example is third-party. Note that different parties have to be different websites. sub.news.example is considered first-party when loaded under news.example because they are considered to be the same site.

But it appears they also adhere strictly to their description of a website as *"a registrable domain including all of its subdomains."*

Comment: What happens about `example1.co.uk` and `example2.co.uk`? surely they must be considered separate domains even though they share a second level domain